# How to display navigation tabs with the desired border? Table, list, something else?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

[image: Diagram]

See the picture above. Each navigation tab needs to have 2 pixels separation on either side and line up exactly with the header image on the edges.

Now they would like to introduce a 5th navigation tab (and possibly a 6th). Is it possible to code this in a way where you could stick a 5th or 6th tab in there and everything would resize appropriately with lists or tables or some other solution?  Still keeping the 2 pixels separation and lining up with the edges exactly?  I wasn't sure if it was possible or you would just have to define the widths each time for each tab based on the math involved to line it all up correctly flush with the edges.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to emulate table behavior with CSS. So you can use a list, and still get table behavior.

```
ul {
    display:table;
}
li {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/pe6wd/) displaying this with CSS and proper markup. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/KjBRV/) of how it looks with an actual table. I'm not certain on IE<8 support for this CSS, so it may be something to be aware of.

**UPDATE**: Confirmed: This is not supported on IE6 or 7 natively. You may be stuck with tables or hard-coded widths if you want to support those browsers. There may be a javascript fix to support these `display` values but I'm not aware of it.

**EDIT**: I realized my demos were sloppy, so I made another that actually addresses your point about the margins, it uses the `:first-child` selector to remove the margin from the first link, giving the evenly distributed appearance. http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/pe6wd/3/

Answer (score 0):

It may not be easy.  One of the requirements in most implementations of css horizontal menu type displays is setting a fixed width for each element.  If you try and do percentages, things start to come apart. However, any thing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at LESS or SASS so you can do simple math in CSS?